# How does one use REJECT in flex?

Tags: parsing, lex, flex-lexer

Let's be clear I'm talking about the lexical analysis tool.

For the following input:

`aa bb cc dd`

I need the parser to match the following sub strings:

`aa bb`

`bb cc`

`cc dd`

I have this regex:

`[a-zA-Z]+[ ]+[a-zA-Z]+`

But this only matches:

`aa bb`

`cc dd`

I've been told the REJECT command can be used to get the output I need but I don't know how to apply it. Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: No, `REJECT` will not help you in this case. You'll want to let the current position of the char inside the lexer jump back 2 places when it matches `[a-zA-Z]+[ ]+[a-zA-Z]+`, while `REJECT` will jump back to the beginning of the rule and will try to match much more. I am not familiar enough with Flex to answer your question though.

Answer (score 0):

REJECT will start the scan over, then you just need to "eat" the first alphabetic string that you already matched. Possibly this is what you wanted (10 years ago :-):

```
%%
[a-zA-Z]+[ ]+[a-zA-Z]+    { printf("found %s\n", yytext); REJECT; }
[a-zA-Z]+[ ]*
```

Given the input string:

```
a b c d e
```

it will produce:

```
found a b
found b c
found c d
found d e
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regex to enumerate n and n + 1 pairs through an entire set.

Look into a grouping with a "greedy" backwards (or forwards) match.

Comment: This question is not about (modern) regular expressions in general, but the lexical tool GNU-Flex, whose regular expressions really _are_ regular (no grouping and all that fancy stuff).

Answer (score -1):

This is one Flex solution to the problem :

```
    %%
    "aa bb"         {printf( "matched aa bb\n");REJECT;}
    "bb cc"         {printf( "matched bb cc\n");REJECT;}
    "cc dd"         {printf( "matched cc dd\n");REJECT;}
    .               /*ignore anything else*/
    %%
    int main()
    {
    yylex();
    return 0;
    }


When I run the code on your input I get :
matched aa bb
matched bb cc
matched cc dd
```

Comment: But by the pattern the OP posted, `[a-zA-Z]+[ ]+[a-zA-Z]+`, it seems that `aa bb cc dd` is a very simplified input example. I know little Flex, but I don't see `REJECT` being used in a more general way. Do you perhaps?